# Proper way to append array data jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, append

I'm building a chat app with javascript database.
It's a realtime and work perfect at local.

After I deploy it to online, the append time delays for a few milliseconds
and it happens like [this image.](https://ibb.co/ch5dm8)

I think it's because I clear the "**ul**" before appending the newly added data.

---

**Here is the codes**

```
$("#chatbox ul").html("");

$.each(messageArr, function(i,message){

            if(!message){
                return;
            }

            var myMsg = "<li class=me id="+message._id+"><p class=what>"+message.what+"</p><p>"+moment(message.when).fromNow()+"  by <strong>"+message.who+"</strong></p></li>";    

            var someoneMsg = "<li class=someone id="+message._id+"><p class=what>"+message.what+"</p><p>"+moment(message.when).fromNow()+"  by <strong>"+message.who+"</strong></p></li>";  

            if(isMe){
               $("#chatbox ul").append(myMsg);
            }else{
               $("#chatbox ul").append(someoneMsg);
            }

  })
```

---

Is there any proper way to loop and append the array data without flashing like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
});
```

Comment: I could send message on submit event and it works fine. I am looking for a better way to loop and append the data (not event). Btw, thank you.